# How to draw lines and get angles from an avi file?

Tags: matlab, angle

I have an avi file of a guy walking. I turned him into a skeleton. I want to ultimately measure the angles from his chest to arms and his hips to his feet. Is there a function or a good way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Use a [Hough transform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/analyzing-images.html#f11-27827) to detect lines of the skeleton, then it is easy to get the angles... This [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/openni-dev/fOaxKHQ8dqk) can also be useful...